# Pyspark dataframe looping using rdd is taking too much time

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

Using spark sql, i got spark dataframe having a few million rows from bigquery in GCP.
For example:

```
df = spark.sql("select id, concated_name from one_table group by id ...")
```

To loop all rows, i used rdd.collect but it's taking lots of time.
For example:

```
for row in df.rdd.collect()
```

Is there any way to loop all rows in the spark dataframe? In my view, there could be possible to split the big data in the spark dataframe into several and process looping one by one. So that timeout problem can not be coming up. Or probably there could be the fastest and best way to loop all.

Comment: In first place, looping will break the entire notion of spark. Can you tell us what you want and accordingly community can help?

Comment: There are millions of records in bigquery database. I used sql query to merge multiple records into one group by id and then i need to loop each rows one by one.
Even though i got spark dataframe using query, i coudn't have looped all rows in the dataframe because of taking too much time to `rdd.collect`.
That's why i'm posting the problem here. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you already have a dataframe. Now, what operation you want to perform using looping?

Comment: Right, i got dataframe from spark.sql.
Then, I wanna write each row value in specific column which has combined data with ','(comma) as csv file in google storage.
That's the reason i'm gonna loop all rows in the dataframe.